# Creating an 'object accessor' function - Deeply nested javascript objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Motivation: Given a deeply nested object, there is 'currency' key at level N.However, level N might not be uniform, meaning that currency key of object A might be located at level 4 and the same key might be located at 9th level of objectB

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a uniform accessor. An instant accessor that would be generated only once and be used when encountered similar array of objects (deeply nested).

Currently, via recursion I've managed to construct the 'accessor path' as a string.
How could I apply this to my object ?
Is it plausible to attempt this? I'd appreciate your input, thought and opinion.

```js
// testObj[level][id][title][name][currency] === 'USD'

const testObj = {
  level: {
    id: {
      title: {
        name: {
          currency: "USD"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// testObj2[a][b][c][currency]
const testObj2 = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        currency: "USD"
      }
    }
  }
}

const testObj3 = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: {
          e: {
            currency: "USD"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const objectAccessCreator = (obj, targetKey, keysArray = []) => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (key !== targetKey) {
      keysArray.push(key);

      if (typeof value !== 'object' || typeof value === null) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return objectAccessCreator(value, 'currency', keysArray);
      }
    }
    if (key === targetKey) {
      keysArray.push(key);
    }
  }

  let accessChain = '';

  for (const key of keysArray) {
    accessChain += `[${key}]`;
  }
  return accessChain;
}

const targetKey = 'currency';

// [a][b][c][d][e][currency]
console.log(objectAccessCreator(testObj3, targetKey));

//[level][id][title][name][currency]
console.log(objectAccessCreator(testObj, targetKey));


//[a][b][c][currency]
console.log(objectAccessCreator(testObj2, targetKey));
```

Comment: You may try something like this : `console.log(eval('testObj3'+ objectAccessCreator(testObj3, targetKey)));`  You need to quote the keys to make this work. And you know `eval` is evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string to a path array, then use `Array.reduce()` to return the property value.

I'd wrap this up in a `getValue()` function that takes an object and path arguments.

```js
const objectAccessCreator = (obj, targetKey, keysArray = []) => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (key !== targetKey) {
      keysArray.push(key);

      if (typeof value !== 'object' || typeof value === null) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return objectAccessCreator(value, 'currency', keysArray);
      }
    }
    if (key === targetKey) {
      keysArray.push(key);
    }
  }

  let accessChain = '';

  for (const key of keysArray) {
    accessChain += `[${key}]`;
  }
  return accessChain;
}

const targetKey = 'currency';

function getValue(obj, path) {
    return path.split(/[\[\]]+/).filter(s => s).reduce((obj, key) => { 
        return obj[key];
    }, obj);
}

const testObjects = [
  { level: { id: { title: { name: { currency: "USD" } } } } },
  { a: { b: { c: { currency: "USD" } } } },
  { a: { b: { c: { d: { e: { currency: "USD" } } } } } }
];
  
for(let testObj of testObjects) { 
    const path = objectAccessCreator(testObj, targetKey);
    console.log('Generated path:', path);
    console.log('Value at path:', getValue(testObj, path));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

I'd also suggest maybe using a '.' separator for the paths, this simplifies the logic somewhat:

```js
const objectAccessCreator = (obj, targetKey, keysArray = []) => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (key !== targetKey) {
      keysArray.push(key);

      if (typeof value !== 'object' || typeof value === null) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return objectAccessCreator(value, 'currency', keysArray);
      }
    }
    if (key === targetKey) {
      keysArray.push(key);
    }
  }

  return keysArray.join('.');
}

const targetKey = 'currency';

function getValue(obj, path) {
    return path.split('.').reduce((obj, key) => { 
        return obj[key];
    }, obj);
}

const testObjects = [
  { level: { id: { title: { name: { currency: "USD" } } } } },
  { a: { b: { c: { currency: "USD" } } } },
  { a: { b: { c: { d: { e: { currency: "USD" } } } } } }
];
  
for(let testObj of testObjects) { 
    const path = objectAccessCreator(testObj, targetKey);
    console.log('Generated path:', path);
    console.log('Value at path:', getValue(testObj, path));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

And an example of returning the `targetKey` value directly from a new `getValue()` function:

```js
const targetKey = 'currency';

function getValue(obj, property) {
    for(let key in obj) {
        if (obj[key] && (typeof(obj[key]) === 'object')) {
            let value = getValue(obj[key], property);
            if (value !== null) {
                return value;
            }
        } else if (key === property) {
            return obj[key];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

const testObjects = [
  { level: { id: { title: { name: { currency: "USD" } } } } },
  { a: { b: { c: { currency: "USD" } } } },
  { a: { b: { c: { d: { e: { currency: "USD" } } } } } }
];
  
for(let testObj of testObjects) { 
    console.log(`Value of "${targetKey}":`, getValue(testObj, targetKey));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you for getValue() function. Pertaining to performance, instead of trying to access this deeply nested property we're trying to access WHILE iterating over an array of these deeply nested objects (which I think would add too much up to complexity since we don't really know beforehand the deepness of the object),  constructing this 'accessor' and then applying that to each object while iterating ought to be MORE OPTIMAL correct ?

Comment: It would be more performant, but I think both functions will run very quickly.

Comment: But in the former case, I don't really know how to access the property 'currency' since we haven't been informed about its level (could be located at 4th or 9th level). This sort of uniformity cannot be achieved If I'm not aware of the shape (deepness) of the data correct ?

Comment: You could create a getValue() function that will return the first 'currency' property it finds in an object tree. I can add an example to the answer above.

Comment: No need for that. Thank you for your time and valuable input.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat simplified approach. `retrievePathAndValue` returns the path and its value in a small object (`{path, value,}`). If you want to retrieve the value later from the resulting path, you can use `[result].path` and some function like the one in the selected answer or something [like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fwg2db?file=index.js) (see [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-sm1jh2?file=index.js) of the latter).

```js
const  [ testObj, testObj2, testObj3 ] = testData();
const targetKey = 'currency';

console.log(retrievePathAndValue(testObj, targetKey));
console.log(retrievePathAndValue(testObj2, targetKey));
console.log(retrievePathAndValue(testObj3, targetKey));

function retrievePathAndValue(obj, key, path = ``) {
  for (let k of Object.keys(obj)) {
    if (obj[key]) {
      return {
        path: `${path}${path.length < 1 ? `` : `.`}${key}`,
        value: obj[key],
      };
    }

    if (obj[k] instanceof Object && !Array.isArray(obj[k])) {
      return retrievePathAndValue(
        obj[k], 
        key, 
        `${path}${path.length < 1 ? `` : `.`}${k}` );
    }
  }
  
  return {
    path: `[${key}] NOT FOUND`,
    value: undefined, 
  };
}

function testData() {
  const testObj = {
    level: {
      id: {
        title: {
          name: {
            currency: "USD"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // testObj2[a][b][c][currency]
  const testObj2 = {
    a: {
      b: {
        c: {
          currency: "USD"
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const testObj3 = {
    a: {
      b: {
        c: {
          d: {
            e: {
              currency: "USD"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return [ testObj, testObj2, testObj3 ];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```